# Accessing my Google Play music

Tags: applications, google-play-music, cloud

Is there an app to access my Google Play music?

I can only access it via the browser. The connection is horrible, as well as the interface.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music)?

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the songs to appear? I'm logged in to my account - the same account I used to set up the playlists on my laptop - but none of my songs appear in the app. I have to use the browser to access the songs.

Comment: @Steve: Have you gone through the instructions on Google's support site? http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?answer=1291788